# Finding php string within string and save as variable

Tags: php

If I had a string of text e.g:

```
<p>Hello world here is the latest news ##news?123## or click here to read more</p>
```

I want to look through the string and find anything starting with `##news?` Then I want to save that and the id `123` and trailing hashes as a variable, so the final output would be:

```
$myvar == "##news?123##"
```

How can I use PHP to read that input string and save that specific part as a variable?

Answer (score 3):

`preg_match` is your friend for this sort of problem.

```
        $str='<p>Hello world here is the latest news ##news?123## or click here to read more';
        $pttn='@(##news\?(\d+)##)@';
        preg_match( $pttn, $str, $matches );

        $myvar=$matches[0];
        $id=$matches[2];

        echo $myvar.' '.$id;
```

Comment: I think your pattern is probably better than mine :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're not trying to parse HTML but as you say, just find any occurrence starting with "##news?" then you can use regex happily here:

```
$string = '<p>Hello world here is the latest news ##news?123## or click here to read more';
$matches = array();
preg_match_all("/(##news\?.*?)\s/",$string,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```